# Unsatisfied dependency through 'sessionFactory'; No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am creating a spring-mvc and hibernate webapp. I am trying to test text read in the book by creating project (hence using xml config). This type of question is asked before but I can't get my project to work with answers offered. I get following error when I hit the end-point :

```
[WARNING] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'categoryDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'categoryDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=sessionFactory)}
[ERROR] Context initialization failed
```

Here is @Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"pizzaml.rest", "pizzaml.service", "pizzaml.dao"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig {
    
    @Bean(name="sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory( @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) throws MalformedURLException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new FileUrlResource("/hibernate-cfg.xml"));
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
    
    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource( @Value("{db.user}") String user, @Value("{db.pass}") String pass, @Value("{db.url}") String url, @Value("{db.driverclass}") String driverClass) {
        BasicDataSource datasource = new BasicDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName(driverClass);
        datasource.setUsername(user);
        datasource.setPassword(pass);
        datasource.setUrl(url);
        
        return datasource;
    }
    
}
```

Here is hibernate-cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        
    <hibernate-configuration>
        
        <session-factory>
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <mapping resource="pizzaml/entity/Category.hbm.xml"></mapping>
        </session-factory>
    
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

DAO-

```
@Repository
public class CategoryDAOImpl implements CategoryDAO {
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public String addCategory(String categoryname) throws BusinessProcessException {
        
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Category.byName");
        List<Category> list = query.list();
        
        if(Objects.nonNull(list) && (!list.isEmpty()) )
            throw new BusinessProcessException("Category already exists!");
        
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setName(categoryname);
        
        session.save(category);
        
        session.flush();
        
        session.close();
        
        return AppCodes.SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
  
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>    
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>./target</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>4500</port>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Feel free to do whatever you prefer, but please be aware that I have been using Spring professionally for about 10 years now and haven't used the old XML style since 2013. Spring Boot is the modern way to do things.

Comment: I understand. I want to do this to cement my understanding of text I read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround for this.

Instead of doing localSessionFactoryBean.getObject() to obtain hibernate session factory.

I used hibernate's configuration class to create session factory object. The only problem was I wanted to give my own datasource. For this I created a class that implemented ConnectionProvider interface. And set property - hibernate.connection.provider_class in hibernate.cfg.xml.

And it started working.

I agree with other comments though, hbm.xmls are old way of doing things. I will learn annotations and start using them in future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something is wrong with your Hibernate mapping, but since you didn't post the entire stacktrace which would help understanding what the error is, there is not much one can do to help you. Apart from that, I would strongly suggest you use the annotation model for Hibernate instead as the HBM XML approach is going to be replaced with the JPA orm.xml approach in one of the upcoming releases.